# add dynamic Multi View from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i try to make an examining system so the admin up lode the question and the choices and the answers i wont to display in user side the question and the chooses in Multi View each view have a question and 3 Radio Button one for each chois
my code only bring me the last question in the table

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE exam_name='" + Request.QueryString["examid"] + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    d1.DataSource = dt;
    d1.DataBind();

    View view = new View();
    Label label = new Label();
    RadioButton RadioButtonA = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton RadioButtonB = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton RadioButtonC = new RadioButton();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        label.Text = dr["qustion"].ToString();
        RadioButtonA.Text= dr["cha"].ToString();
        RadioButtonB.Text = dr["chb"].ToString();
        RadioButtonC.Text = dr["chc"].ToString();
        view.Controls.Add(label);
        view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonA);
        view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonB);
        view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonC);
        m1.Views.Add(view);
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        m1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }

    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the instance outside the loop so every time when the program enters the loop. It only rewrites the text of existing controls instead of creating new ones.That's why it seems like only the last question remains.

What you want should be like

```
View view;
Label label;
RadioButton RadioButtonA, RadioButtonB, RadioButtonC;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    view = new View();
    label = new Label();
    RadioButtonA = new RadioButton();
    RadioButtonB = new RadioButton();
    RadioButtonC = new RadioButton();

    label.Text = dr["qustion"].ToString();
    RadioButtonA.Text= dr["cha"].ToString();
    RadioButtonB.Text = dr["chb"].ToString();
    RadioButtonC.Text = dr["chc"].ToString();
    view.Controls.Add(label);
    view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonA);
    view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonB);
    view.Controls.Add(RadioButtonC);
    m1.Views.Add(view);
}
```